# Hypothesis Testing for different distribution

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

Assume that $X$ is a random variable from a distribution with density function $f$. Find the most powerful test of size-$\alpha$ to test $$H_0:X\sim G(1,1)$$
$$H_1: X\sim N(1,1)$$

I know that I need to use Neyman Pearson Lemma usually to solve this kind of question. But normally I am given the parameter (like $\theta$) for this type of questions. But now I am not really sure how to proceed.

I would appreciate any help or hints.

Comment: What is $G$?$\text{}$

Comment: $G$ is gamma dsitribution, $N$ is normal distribution

Comment: The method is same: You find the likelihood ratio $f_{H_1}/f_{H_0}$ and reject $H_0$ for large values of this ratio.

Comment: that's mean I just substitute 1 into the parameter and evaluate them?

Answer (score 1):

You can think of the situation like this:

$$X\sim \theta \,\Gamma(1,1)+(1-\theta)N(1,1)\,,\quad\theta\in\{0,1\}$$

You are to test $H_0:\theta=1$ against $H_1:\theta=0$, i.e. a simple null versus a simple alternative.

But to actually solve the problem, there is no need to introduce any parameter $\theta$.

**Hint:**

Follow the standard procedure. Let $f$ be the density of $X$. Find the likelihood ratio $f_{H_1}/f_{H_0}$, where $f_{H_j}$ is the pdf of $X$ under $H_j$, $j=0,1$. By Neyman-Pearson lemma, a most powerful test rejects $H_0$ whenever the ratio $f_{H_1}/f_{H_0}$ is large. Simplify the rejection region from there and hence find the exact test.

Comment: Ya, this is the standard procedure. After I evaluated their density function, I just substitute $\alpha=1$ ,$\lambda=1$, $\mu = 1$, and $\sigma^2=1$ into the equation right?

Comment: If they are the parameters of your distributions, yes.